# Request getting timed out when using parameter encoding JSONEncoding.default

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire for carrying out all network related requests in my app. I am facing problem while encoding parameter as JSON in get request.

Following in my request:

```
 Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
 .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
     switch response.result {
     case .success(let retrivedResult):
         print(retrivedResult)
//         success(brandTags)
         break
     case .failure(let errorGiven):
         print(errorGiven)
         print(String(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "")
         failure(APICaller.parseErrorAndGiveMessage(givenError: errorGiven as NSError))
         break
     }
 })
```

When I encode the parameters as `JSONEncoding.default` as above, the request always times out with following in my logs:

```
2016-12-27 12:22:41.425948 xyz[5140:133008] [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [2.1 35.164.98.40:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 4294967295 frame count, 0 byte count
2016-12-27 12:23:41.485534 xyz[5140:133041] [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [2.1 35.164.98.40:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 4294967295 frame count, 0 byte count

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000024a9b0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xyz-beta.abc.com/v1/brands/1a1/notifications, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xyz-beta.abc.com/v1/brands/1a1/notifications, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
2016-12-27 12:23:41.488336 xyz[5140:133868] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled
```

But when I remove the parameter encoding like below, the request completes properly without any problem.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
     .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
         switch response.result {
         case .success(let retrivedResult):
             print(retrivedResult)
    //         success(brandTags)
             break
         case .failure(let errorGiven):
             print(errorGiven)
             print(String(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "")
             failure(APICaller.parseErrorAndGiveMessage(givenError: errorGiven as NSError))
             break
         }
     })
```

What is the making the difference?

**UPDATE:**

I opened this issue with Alamofire community on Github and [this is their response](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1879#issuecomment-269573257). Hope this helps people who faced similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So according to the Alamofire community on the [issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1879#issuecomment-269573257) I opened on GitHub for my above question, they suggest that this is a very common behaviour seen many times and the solution to this is `URLEncoding.queryString` encode the parameters in the `GET` request because some servers don't like `bodyData` in `GET` request.

So essentially my request code was modified like this:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString)
 .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
     switch response.result {
     case .success(let retrivedResult):
         print(retrivedResult)
//         success(brandTags)
         break
     case .failure(let errorGiven):
         print(errorGiven)
         print(String(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "")
         failure(APICaller.parseErrorAndGiveMessage(givenError: errorGiven as NSError))
         break
     }
 })
```

And this perfectly worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried and success:

Cast your param as `[String: AnyObject]`

```
let params: [String: AnyObject] = ["param1": value1 as AnyObject, "param2": value2 as AnyObject]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please refer to my updated question for future reference.

Comment: Yes, I will check. Same problem here :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. In my Router, I had my GET requests using JSONEncoding:

> urlRequest = try JSONEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with:
>   parameters)

To fix it, I changed it to URLEncoding:

> urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with:
>   parameters)